# How can I count the number of times each directive is invoked (Angular 1.*)?

Tags: angularjs

I am currently profiling a huge Angular 1.5 app. As part of this exercise, I'm trying to print a list of each directive and how many times it's invoked. I'd like to include both custom directives and built-in ones (like ng-if).

I took the approach of instrumenting the Angular source code in different ways (e.g. by adding counters to addDirective). However, everything I've tried so far I seem to under-count the directives.

Is there someone who's familiar with Angular internals? If so, do you know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all directives are available as Angular services and retrieved on every directive compilation, the most simple way of doing this is to patch injector:

```
app.run(($injector) => {
  $injector._get = $injector.get;

  $injector.get = function (name) {
    var instance = this._get.apply(this, arguments);

    if (/Directive$/.test(name)) {
      var countPerDirectiveName = instance
      .map(ddo => ddo.multiElement ? 0.5 : 1)
      .reduce((countPerDirectiveName, count) => countPerDirectiveName + count)

      console.log(name, countPerDirectiveName);
    };

    return instance;
  }
});
```

It is also possible to take control over directives by patching `$compileProvider.directive`, but it would be hard to do that for built-in directives because they are registered in core `ng` module, before `$compileProvider` could be patched in user module.

Comment: Thanks -- this is very cool! But it still seems to under-count custom attribute directives sometimes. I spent some time trying to understand why, but the flow was difficult to follow (_maybe_ it's some optimization involving the reuse of objects in postlink functions?). Do you know if patching $compileProvider would be more reliable? I don't mind patching the Angular source code itself for my local run.

Comment: Can you provide an example that replicates the problem? I don't think it is possible that it undercounts something. I guess it is roughly the same thing as `addDirective` patch. You can try to patch compile function after [this piece of code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/compile.js#L1101-L1105) with something like `var _compile = directive.compile; directive.compile = function () { console.log(this.name); return _compile.apply(this, arguments) }`, but I suppose that the result should be similar.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. Unfortunately, our app is very big and complex, and I wasn't able to easily generate an isolated repro. I'll give your suggestion about $compileProvider a try. Thanks again for the ideas!